# Plotting Multiple BoxPlots by Date

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, boxplot

New to R and appreciate advice! I am trying to plot multiple boxplots on the same graph, split by date. My data is saved in a .csv, and the code I am trying right now is the following. I suspect my as.Date function is not working appropriately. Any help is much appreciated!
Data is in csv columns of "Day" and "Strength". Date formatting in the .csv is, for example, "5/1/21" for May 1, 2021.

```
FG <- read.csv("/Users/L/Downloads/ResultsFG.csv", header=T, na.strings=c(""))

library(ggplot2)

FG$Day <- as.Date(FG$Day)
FG$Day <- format(FG$Day, "%b-%d")
FG$Day <- factor(FG$Day, levels=c("May-1","May-2","May-3", "May-4", "May-5", "May-6", "May-7", "May-87", "May-9", "May-10", "May-11", "May-14", "Mar-17", "May-18", "May-19", "May-20", "May-21", "May-22", "May-24", "May-25", "May-26", "May-27", "May-28", "May-29", "May-30", "May-31"))

ggplot() + 
geom_boxplot(data = FG, aes(x = factor(Day, level = d_order), y = Strength), color = "forestgreen", fill= "forestgreen", alpha = 0.1)
```

I don't get any error messages, but I do get one large boxplot labeled on the X axis as "NA". (screenshot below) Can you help me split this by date?

[single boxplot generated, X axis = "NA"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO9D3.png)

ETA: Strange result after I call the Day column after trying to convert it

```
> FG$Day
  [1] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
  [9] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [17] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [25] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [33] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [41] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   May-21 May-21 May-21 May-21
 [49] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [57] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [65] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [73] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [81] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [89] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
 [97] <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
26 Levels: May-1 May-2 May-3 May-4 May-5 May-6 May-7 ... May-31
```

Comment: The please submit a reprex army will be along shortly. Your code is OK. But without the CSV we can't exactly replicate.

Comment: But you should have an x OR a y data not both. Your X needs to be moved to group=Day

Comment: I'm trying to have my X be the date... Multiple boxplots, one over each date.

Comment: We can't possibly help if you aren't showing us the data that goes in. You need to as a minimum show us: head(FG$Day) before and after each line of code

Comment: Here is a tip though. as.Date("5/1/21") will normally give "0005-01-21" because it's an ambiguous format. as.Date("5/1/21", tryFormats = "%m/%d/%y") will give "2021-05-01" which is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide your sample data, you can try this.

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)

FG <- gapminder[1:444,]

FG$Day <- FG$year
FG$Day <- factor(FG$Day, levels=unique(FG$Day))
FG$Strength <- FG$lifeExp

ggplot(data = FG, aes(x = factor(Day), y = Strength, fill= "forestgreen", color="red")) + 
   geom_boxplot( alpha = 0.1) +
   scale_fill_manual(values="forestgreen") +
   scale_color_manual(values="red")
```

[image: output]

Comment: I don't think there is a need for factor on the X= in ggplot as it's already been factored

Comment: I agree.  I was just trying to leave the code as is - as I am not sure how his data frame is set-up.